# Replace NULL arguments with "0"

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to replace NULL arguments to "0"?

I have a function:

```
f<-function(a=NULL,b=NULL,c=NULL){
}
```

I wont be calling all the arguments of this function, so sometimes, it could be f(a,b) and c should default to "0" inside the function. How do I get this?

Comment: Add within the function `if (is.null(c)) { c <- 0 }`

Comment: If I call f(a,c), then b should default to 0. Is there a way to automatically pick the undefined arguments and assign them 0?. Actually, I have many variables- f(a,b,c....z) . I may use any number of variables and other variables will be unused and I want to assign them 0

Comment: Why don't you set them to zero in the function arguments?

Comment: Then just change to `f<-function(a=0, b=0, c=0){ ... }`

Comment: Will I be able to pass optional arguments if I set it to 0 initially?

Comment: Yes, if you call `f(a = 1)` then it will supersede the default.

Comment: This works, But for another function to execute inside this function, I have to declare  as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, chapter [10.3 Named arguments and defaults](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Named-arguments-and-defaults) of [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) says:

> In many cases arguments can be given commonly appropriate default
>   values, in which case they may be omitted altogether from the call
>   when the defaults are appropriate. For example, if `fun1` were defined
>   as
>
> ```
> fun1 <- function(data, data.frame, graph=TRUE, limit=20) {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> it could be called as
>
> ```
> ans <- fun1(d, df)
> ```
>
> which is now equivalent to the three cases above, or as
>
> ```
> ans <- fun1(d, df, limit=10)
> ```
>
> which changes one of the defaults.
>
> It is important to note that defaults may be arbitrary expressions,
>   even involving other arguments to the same function; they are not
>   restricted to be constants as in our simple example here.